# Reputation system seems unfair

Tags: discussion

Why must I gain reputation before I can comment?  I'd like to be pro active and help people out who have unanswered questions.  But many need clarification before I can give an appropriate answer. I can't ask them because I can't comment or contact them.  To me,  this seems like a setup to keep those in power where they are and the newcomer at the bottom.

Comment: Took me 3 days of rep building to get there.  Keep at it!  I'm sure everyone knows something they can help with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must gain reputation because, as it says in the help, commenting is a privilege.

What I did was dive in with a few answers, and if they're good enough they get up-voted and accepted, and before long you're at your magic 50.

... or you could just ask some good questions!

Comment: Heck, just suggest 25 edits.

Comment: It seems also unfair to me regarding comments. 50 is too much for such privilege.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli too much? 5 answers with 1 upvote, 25 accepted suggested edits, 10 upvotes on questions, I don't see how this, (or any combination of these) could be seen as "too much"

Comment: Remember that having set minimums for chat also help to prevent spammers and bots. You can see this often in most online video-games where there are global chats. Often rules are set into place where the player needs a minimum level or some other form of blockage that is harder for a computer to obtain than simply creating an account and logging in.  Also, kudos to Ian, another person with the same name as I! :D

Comment: I would halve the requirement...